# How to flag Outlyingness using Stanhel-Donoho Estimator in R

Tags: r, data-analysis, outliers, robust, mahalanobis

Please, I need help to successfully run the Stanhel and Donoho Estimator on my data to flag outlyingness. I have a four column data with the summary presented below:

[Data Summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oyt9S.png)

I did some study on Stanhel and Donoho estimator with some good help from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/123262/how-to-find-set-of-directions-in-stahel-donoho-outlyingness-measure?newreg=c30edbef495a4cca857e27f3c1d584b1). I discover one of the problems I may have with my data is the presence of zeros. How do I handle this and correctly flag outlyingness using [outlyingness](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mrfDepth/versions/1.0.14/topics/outlyingness) function in r?

At the moment, I get this warning in r:

[Warning Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTAtL.png)

And the result returns NULL for outlyingnessX, outlyingnessZ, cuttoff, flagX, flagZ, singularSubsets and dimension.

If possible, please suggest an alternative or adjusted method to flag outlyingness.

Comment: You're more likely to get help if you include a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Please edit your question to include the code (not an image of it) and a sample of some data.